# How to get full url in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

My app takes advantage of Angular Universal and I'd like to get the full path of the current `url` in an Angular component. I think I have to use the `window` object where I may need to inject the window or maybe the better option is to simply check if it's in the browser. Are there any cleaner solutions utilizing Angular's API?

```
  url: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      this.url = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}${window.location.pathname}`;
    });
  }
```

Edit: The question I'm asking is how to get the full `url` in a way that is compliant with Angular Universal

Comment: try like this : console.log("location", window.location.href);

Comment: Edited to clarify the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Express, you can inject the url from express to your component

Step #1: modify your node server to pass the url you want

```
//Get index.html file contents from dist/browser/index.html
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist'); 
const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();


app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
var fullUrl = options.req.protocol + '://' + options.req.get('host') + options.req.originalUrl;

  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    // DI so that we can get lazy-loading to work differently (since we need it to just instantly render it)
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      {
        provide: 'serverUrl',
        useValue: fullUrl
      }
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});
```

Step #2: In your component/service, add an optionnal parameter

```
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object, @Optional() @Inject('serverUrl') protected serverUrl: string)
{
 // Here, this.serverUrl will have a value only when using angular universal
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, should give me a value and not just be blank until the browser takes over. I'll mark as the answer once I make sure it works.

Comment: David I copy pasted your code and only replaced `template` with`'./src/index.html'`. After that I am getting this error and application won't run  `The selector "app-root" did not match any elements.`

Comment: @user7747472 the `document` property must be the html of the `index.html` file, not a path. I edited my answer

Comment: @David, Oh okay i got it. This `DIST_FOLDER` is it some magic function or like a constant. I m sorry I m noobie to angular

Comment: Ty David that helped a lot and finally got it working . :)