# Angular 7 : How can i get the complete URL of the current page

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, angular-universal

How can I get the complete current URL in angular 7 without using `window.location.href`?

For example, let's say my current URL is `http://localhost:8080/p/drinks?q=cold&price=200`

How can I get the complete URL rather than only `/p/drinks?q=cold&price=200`?

I have tried with `this.router.url` this gives only `/p/drinks?q=cold&price=200` not with the complete hostname.

The reason that I do not want to use `window.location.href` is that it causes an issue with rendering in [ng-toolkit/universal](https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit)

I tried to follow this solution which seems to be a same problem as me and also updated

[How to get domain name for service in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222845/how-to-get-domain-name-for-service-in-angular2)

And here is my code

**windowProvider.js**

```
import { InjectionToken, FactoryProvider } from '@angular/core';

export const WINDOW = new InjectionToken<Window>('window');

const windowProvider: FactoryProvider = {
  provide: WINDOW,
  useFactory: () => window
};

export const WINDOW_PROVIDERS = [
  windowProvider
];
```

In **app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    .......
    providers:[
    .......
    windowProvider
   ]
})
```

And in my required page :

```
import {WINDOW as WindowFactory} from '../../factory/windowProvider';
......
 constructor(private router: Router, private helper: Helpers,
             @Inject(WindowFactory) private windowFactory: any,
            ) {
console.warn('HELLO I M WINDOW FACTORY', this.windowFactory.location.hostname);
}
```

Buy this gives error at the time of compilation

> ERROR in ./src/app/factory/windowProvider.js 5:20 Module parse failed:
>   Unexpected token (5:20) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | export const WINDOW = new
>   InjectionToken('window'); |
>
> > const windowProvider: FactoryProvider = { |   provide: WINDOW, |   useFactory: () => window ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Can anyone please tell how I can get this resolved. Thanks,

- [How to get base url in angular 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984268/how-to-get-base-url-in-angular-5)
- [How to get the current url in the browser in Angular 2 using TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796449/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-the-browser-in-angular-2-using-typescript)
- [How to get current route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597835/how-to-get-current-route)

More links that I followed:

Comment: See here if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/47205502/1160794

Comment: @David, I checked the link seems like that might work but i am unable to get it to work. I have commented on your answer can you please have a look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The universal server side isn't aware of the window.location.

The express server on the other hand knows the url from the request that was being sent to the server side.

So we need to inject the request url from express into angular..

*server.ts*

```
let template = readFileSync(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
    renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
        document: template,
        url: options.req.url,
        extraProviders: [
            { provide: 'requestUrl', useFactory: () => options.req.url, deps: [] },    // 1. set up the provider for the url
            provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
        ]
    }).then(html => {
        callback(null, html);
    });
});
```

..in order to retrieve it where we need it..

*url-logger.ts*

```
class UrlLogger {
    constructor(
        private window: Location,
        private injector: Injector,                         // 2. we need the injector to ..
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: string,
    ) { }

    public log() {
        if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
            const requestUrl = this.injector.get('requestUrl');    // 3. ..retrieve the injected url
            console.log('server greets you via ' + requestUrl)
        } else {
            console.log('browser says hello from ' + window.location.href)
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: `template` is a constant or like what it is. If i import it from angular core then it throws error

Comment: `template` is the complete path to your template index.html:

"The renderModuleFactory() function takes as inputs a template HTML page (usually index.html), an Angular module containing components, and a route that determines which components to display"
[citation from angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/universal#universal-web-servers).

I also edited the answer accordingly.